# R trying to predict future population

Tags: r

There may be a a pretty easy solution but I'm new at R so I'm having a hard time trying to understand getting this solution for this exercise im figuring out.

I basically have the following data and want to predict a linear regression of the following data for 2020.

> data
>      Geographic.Area   Census Estimates.Base    X2010    X2011    X2012    X2013
>   15         Florida 18801310       18804592 18849098 19096952 19344156 19582022
>         X2014    X2015    X2016 X2020
>   15 19888741 20244914 20612439     0

Each year is its own column with 2020 having a value of 0. Trying to predict its value.

I know I have to start out with something in the following path:

> linear = lm(X2020 ~ years, data=data)

But am getting errors and the returned numbers arent correct. How should I continue with this? The answer might be pretty simple but im still trying to understand how this works so I can predict the 2020 value.

Edit:
As for code I have done the following which I can see is wrong. But unsure as to what steps to take to correct it.

> linear = lm(X2020 ~ X2010 + X2011 + X2012 + X2013 + X2014 + X2015 + X2016, data=florida)
>   linear

Call:
lm(formula = X2020 ~ X2010 + X2011 + X2012 + X2013 + X2014 + 
    X2015 + X2016, data = florida)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)        X2010        X2011        X2012        X2013        X2014
          0           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA
      X2015        X2016
         NA           NA

Comment: Please include the code that you have till now and the error messages you get. It will help  others to help you.

Comment: If the years are to be predictor variables it would be better to do a time-series model. Otherwise, I'd suggest creating a variable Year with the years as values instead of variables.

Comment: I actually did do that. I made a new variable years with populations from 2010-2016. But unsure how i can use that to predict the 2020 population. Also, im doing this exercise to learn how to build linear regression model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to conduct this analysis with `lm()`. Since the OP data source didn't match years to population values, I used data from the American Fact Finder.

```
 # data from https://factfinder.census.gov/faces/tableservices/jsf/pages/productview.xhtml?src=CF

rawData <- "state year population
FL 2010 18511620
FL 2011 18688767
FL 2012 18885152
FL 2013 19091156
FL 2014 19361792
FL 2015 19645772
FL 2016 19934451"

flPopulation <- read.table(textConnection(rawData),header=TRUE)
theModel <- lm(population ~ year,data = flPopulation)
year <- 2017:2020 
predictions <- (year * theModel$coef[2]) + theModel$coef[1]
summary(theModel) 
data.frame(year,predictions)
```

...and the output:

```
> summary(theModel)

Call:
lm(formula = population ~ year, data = flPopulation)

Residuals:
     1      2      3      4      5      6      7 
 65284   4604 -36837 -68660 -35850  10303  61156 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -459585001   21171220  -21.71 3.85e-06 ***
year            237826      10517   22.61 3.14e-06 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 55650 on 5 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9903,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9884 
F-statistic: 511.3 on 1 and 5 DF,  p-value: 3.144e-06

> data.frame(year,predictions)
  year predictions
1 2017    20111122
2 2018    20348948
3 2019    20586775
4 2020    20824601
>
```

Comment: Aweomse thank you!!! Looks like i was on the right path. But the way i had my data organized and inputing for lm () was a bit off. Thank you so much now i understand it better ☺

Comment: @BryanRamirez You're welcome. As you learn about how to access the contents of the model object generated by `lm()` and other modeling algorithms, you'll discover many interesting things you can do with the model output